# Django-registration issues with namespaces

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using django-registration 2.12 and django 1.10.

I am trying to use django-registration. If I include `app_name` in my `urls.py` I get the error

```
Reverse for 'auth_password_reset' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

for the login url.

My urls.py for the app is

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

app_name = 'my_app'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index_view, name='index'),
    url(r'^about$', views.about_view, name='about'),
    url(r'^data$', views.data_view, name='data'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Normally I would expect `include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')` to go in your root `urls.py` file, which would avoid namespace issues. Do you really need to include the registration urls in your app's urls rather than the root url config?

Comment: No I don't. I will try that.

Comment: Yes. That fixed it. Cheers